# Can you sync an iphone/ipad while running Ubuntu from "try me" on usb?

Tags: 18.04, usb, sync, iphone

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 through the "try me" function off a USB key

I have made all the relevant settings but when I connect my Iphone 7 or Ipad 1 I can't sync through rhythm box. I am able to see the phones internal directory through the file browser but it doesn't appear as a device on rhythm box.

I have tried the following, in order:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice6 libimobiledevice-dev
sudo apt-get install -y ifuse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```